# ¿ Como asignar contador como parte del nombre de clase, que ya tienen los Divs ( Usando php ,Jquery )?

Tags: php, jquery

Mi problema es que quiero crear varios elementos segun la cantidad que encuentre el siclo While y asigne el contador concatenado con al nombre de La CLASE que ya tiene ( QUE ES : ELEMENTO ); tambien asignarle el contador como identificador; como lo podran VER EN EL OTRO CODIO QUE LES ENVIARE, LE DaRE EL NOMBRE AL DOCUMENTO HECHO EN HTML

**Este en el Codigo que Quiero Resolver Usando Jquery Php y Mysql**

```css
  #campoBusq {
  border: 1px solid blue ;
  width:45%;
  float:left;
  padding:5px;
  height:300px;

  }

  #categoria {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width:45%;
  padding:5px;
  float:left;
  height:300px;
  }

  .elemento {
  border: 1px solid green;
  width:90%;
  margin:1%;
  padding:1%;
  float:left;
  clear:left;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="campoBusq"></div>
 <div id="categoria">

  <?php 
   include('../configuracion/conexion.php'); 
  ?>

  <script>
   <?php 
    $consulta = "SELECT idCategoria FROM buscar_categoria";
    $resultado = $conexion->query($consulta) or die("Error de busqueda o conexion");

     while ($datosCateorias=$resultado->fetch_assoc() ) {
   ?>  
     var datosCateorias = '<?php echo $datosCateorias['idCategoria'] ?>';
        $('#categoria').append('<option class="elemento '+contador+'" ident="'+contador+'" >' + datosCateorias + '</option>');

   <?php  
          }

       mysqli_free_result($resultado);
       $conexion->close();
   ?>



  </script>
 </div>
</div>
```

**El script me da este mensaje DONDE NO SE IMPRIME LOS VALORES [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]**

Comment: No te sale porque estás escuchando a Nicky Jam ya me fijé UuU

Comment: Gamez, por favor [edit] tu pregunta, no se si usas mayúsculas intencionalmente, pero puede dificultar la comprensión de tu pregunta para otros usuarios.

Comment: Ok amio gracias por tu consejo, lo tomare en cuenta

Answer (score 0):

Pruébalo así. No es necesario utilizar javascript ni jquery en esa parte, pues lo único que estás haciendo es crear contenido html y eso se puede hacer con php muy sencillamente. Creé la variable contador porque no la vi en ningún lado por tu código.

```
<div id="campoBusq"></div>
    <div id="categoria">

        <?php 
            include('../configuracion/conexion.php'); 

            $consulta = "SELECT idCategoria FROM buscar_categoria";
            $resultado = $conexion->query($consulta) or die("Error de busqueda o conexion");
            contador = 0;
                while ($datosCateorias=$resultado->fetch_assoc() ) {
                    contador++;
                    echo "<option class='elemento ".contador."' iden='".contador."'>". $datosCateorias['idCategoria']."</option>";
                }
                  mysqli_free_result($resultado);
                $conexion->close();
        ?>  
    </div>
</div>
```

Tu código completo quedará así (todo con sus etiquetas correspondientes abiertas y cerradas, se las pones):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

            $('#categoria').on('click','.elemento',function() {
               var e = $(this).clone();
               var identificador = $(this).attr("iden");

               if($("#campoBusq").find("."+identificador).length){

               }else{
                 $(e).appendTo('#campoBusq');
               } 
           });

            $('#campoBusq').on('click','.elemento',function() {
               $(this).remove();
            });

        });

        #campoBusq {
        border: 1px solid blue ;
        width:45%;
        float:left;
        padding:5px;
        height:300px;

        }

        #categoria {
        border: 1px solid red;
        width:45%;
        padding:5px;
        float:left;
        height:300px;
        }

        .elemento {
        border: 1px solid green;
        width:90%;
        margin:1%;
        padding:1%;
        float:left;
        clear:left;
        }




  <div id="campoBusq"></div>
    <div id="categoria">

        <?php 
            include('../configuracion/conexion.php'); 

            $consulta = "SELECT idCategoria FROM buscar_categoria";
            $resultado = $conexion->query($consulta) or die("Error de busqueda o conexion");
            contador = 0;
                while ($datosCateorias=$resultado->fetch_assoc() ) {
                    contador++;
                    echo "<option class='elemento ".contador."' iden='".contador."'>". $datosCateorias['idCategoria']."</option>";
                }
                  mysqli_free_result($resultado);
                $conexion->close();
        ?>  
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: asi si va a funcionar pero como uso las funciones del jquery

Comment: Pues sólo úsalas y ya xd no tienes que hacer nada, nomás pégalas en etiquetas <script></script> y ya.

Comment: Voy a modficar el codio para que lo veas completo

Comment: Creo que estoy confundido; porque primero tengo que crear los DIVS  como esta en la ultima Pregunta; que tiene el Titulo de (HECHO EN HTML ), luego; de crear los html es que hago los script para que cumplan la funcion, justo al elemento que se le de click

Comment: El crearlos primos o segundo o tercero, etc, no depende ciertamente de ti. Depende de la prioridad que los navegadores les dan. Por ejemplo, cuando usas html y un lenguaje de servidor esto se ejecutan y se forman unos con el otro casi al mismo tiempo. Primero el html porque es por la parte del cliente, luego el código del servidor y luego explícitamente le estás diciendo a jQuery que cuando el documento esté listo se ejecuten las funciones jQuery..

Comment: Si todo el código lo tienes embebido ahí primero se creará el html, luego el php te va a crear los optiones y luego se ejecutarán las funciones de jQuery. ¿Cómo puedes hacer funcionar las funciones de jQuery? Pues hasta que le des clic a un elemento con clase "elemento" dentro de #categoria.

Comment: Así quedaría tu código como te lo acabo de actualizar. Procura abrir y cerrar las etiquetas html y script que hacen falta.

Comment: En las imagenes que te mande puedes notar en el inspetor; que se creo los divs perfectamente pero en el documento aparece los bloques vacios

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55151/discussion-between-user2930137-and-gamez).

Comment: y para rematar los divs se ejecutaron en el body y no en el div de categoria

Comment: Necesito ver el código exctamente como lo tienes. Edita tu pregunta y pega todo el código de una.

Comment: Sí hiciste el cambio que te puse como respuesta?

Comment: voy abrir otra pregunta te aviso por aqu cuando lo publique

Comment: pero otra pregunta para qué? xD

Comment: Listo ya esta publicado; es este ; ¿ Porque los Divs no se Muestran dentro del DIv?